# Dplyr or R basis. How to select (or delete) lines that have identical values (column 1 and column 2) and keeping column 3 values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In a data.frame class object with {dplyr} or R {base}.
How to select (or delete) lines that have identical values in column 1 and column 2 ( and keeping column's 3 values).

I have no idea (use distinct fonction?)

```
test <- data.frame(column1 = c("paris","moscou", "rennes"),
                   column2 =  c("paris", "lima", "rennes"), 
                   column3 =c(12,56,78))

> print (test)
column1 column2 column3
1   paris   paris      12
2  moscou    lima      56
3  rennes  rennes      78
```

Example:
line 1: paris paris
line 4: rennes rennes

```
library(dplyr)
test2 <- test %>%
    filter(column1 == column2)

print (test2)
```

Error: level sets of factors are different

Comment: From `library(dplyr)` use `filter(test, column1 == column2)`

Comment: Thank you but not working for me (Error: level sets of factors are different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, use `filter` to retrieve specific **rows** and use `select` to retrieve specific **columns**.

For `data.frame`s you need to `as.character` to match strings:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  filter(as.character(column1) == as.character(column2))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(test, as.character(column1) == as.character(column2))
```

Comment: Thank you but not working for me (Error: level sets of factors are different)

Comment: @Wilcar Convert to `character` class and it should work

Comment: or: `test[as.character(test$column1) == as.character(test$column2),]`